# Convert unit of measurement for a buffer area

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, buffer, area

I have generated buffers around geocoded points on a map. The shape areas for buffers are clearly different than the shape areas generated when projecting polygons (such as tracts, CDPs, or counties). For example, the shape area for a 10mi buffer is approximately 0.097. How can I convert the buffer shape areas to the same unit of measurement as these other polygons (the other polygon units seem to be in square feet)? I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Step 1: Tell us, which software you're working with. Step 2: Convert: Either your data to a different CRS, or calculate manually.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hi Erik, I am using ArcGIS Pro. I have updated the post to reflect this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You should review existing Questions with `!shape!.getArea()` in `CalculateField`, then document the spatial reference of your layer and how you are calculating the reported area within the Question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "shape area" field generated by ArcGIS Pro is expressed in the same unit as the CRS. You can check the properties of the CRS by right-clicking "Map" in your "Contents" panel, opening the properties > source > coordinate systems > details.

To obtain the area of a polygon in a specific unit, you can add a new field and calculate the area with the "Calculate Geometry Attributes" tool. This tool allows you to choose the unit you want your result expressed in.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was incredibly helpful!!

Comment: @JoshuaScott if the answer was helpful, upvote it, if it solved your problem, accept it by hitting the checkmark to it. If neither was the case, you can leave a comment.